# libdevice not found at tensorflow search path

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently working on practicing Tensorflow and have begun the process of installing CUDA and CUDNN. However, when attempting to run my first model, I encountered the following error message:

```
"libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
[[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall_2}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_755]"
```

Fortunately, I discovered that copying the "libdevice.10.bc" file from my CUDA directory at `"/usr/lib/cuda/nvvm/libdevice"` to my script folder resolved the issue, and the script ran perfectly.

Now, I would like to know how I can add the CUDA path to the Tensorflow search path to avoid encountering this error in the future. My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @ Deniel, It seems this is know issue in Ubuntu 22.05. Could you please refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) at the step 6 in step by step instructions section and follow the mentioned commands to fix this error. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.